# How to stop Animate animation when reaching a defined value

Tags: animation

I have following code

```
Animate[
Plot[myvariable x,{x,0,100}
],
{myvariable,0.1,1},AnimationRunning->If[myvariable==1,False,True]
]
```

How do I make the animation stop automatically when reaching a defined value?

NOTE: I tried to make it stop by evaluating myvariable in a If expression, but I get the error  "*An unrecognized option name ("AnimationRunning") was encountered while reading a AnimatorBox.*"

Comment: Given your example, you could just set `AnimationRunning -> True, AnimationRepetitions -> 1`

Comment: Post is an answer an I will mark as the answer, Thanx for answering so fast :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition in your case is to stop at the maximum value of the parameter. This can be achieved by setting the number of animation repetitions to 1 (i.e., no looping):

```
Animate[Plot[myvariable x, {x, 0, 100}], {myvariable, 0.1, 1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> True, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1
]
```

Answer (score 7):

Mathematica is very flexible when it comes to these sorts of things. You can easily build your own little animation, and add as much complexity to the logic of termination by using `Dynamic` directly.

For example, this plots `Cos[a x]` and stops the animation when `a>0.2`.

```
Clear[p];
Dynamic[p]
Do[p = Plot[Cos[a x], {x, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {x, 
      Style[Column[{"doing my own animation !", Cos[a x]}, 
        Alignment -> Center], 14]}}, GridLines -> Automatic];
 If[a > 0.2, Break[]]; (*condition to stop*)
 Pause[.2],
 {a, 0.1, 1, .01}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 for a method I really don't think I would have considered.

Comment: +1 Because you did the work to allow a more general stopping condition than the question asked for.