# Resetting an animation with a custom button

Tags: graphics, dynamic, manipulate, animation

I have the following code, which accepts a function via an `InputField`, and then gradually draws that function in a `Plot` using `Animate`:

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{f = "x^2-1", dummy = False}, 
Column[{Row[{InputField[Dynamic[f], String, 
   ContinuousAction -> True], 
  Dynamic[Button["Plot!", dummy = Not[dummy]]]}], 
Dynamic[Animate[
  Plot[If[x < Time, ToExpression[f], Undefined], {x, -5, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], {Time, -5, 5}, 
  LabelStyle -> White, AnimationRunning -> True]]}]]]
```

The problem is the animation is running constantly; and setting `AnimationRepetitions->1` means that even after updating the function, the plot will stop redrawing. What I'd like to do is have it so that the `Plot` region is only updated when the **Plot!** button is clicked. When it is clicked, the plot is drawn gradually, as above, but *only once*. To do this, I would need to be able to reset the animation from the **Plot!** button itself, and that doesn't seem possible.  I thought `Clock[]` might offer an elegant solution, but I think it is also impossible to reset those.

So, is there a way to do what I describe? Namely, have a graphics region that is only updated when a certain button is clicked, and when it updates an animation runs exactly once?

Comment: Related: [(17571)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17571/121) (not a solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Try this to control the time:

```
test = True;

DynamicModule[{u = 0},
 Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[#, ImageSize -> {480, 15}] &@
  Dynamic@
   If[test,
     Refresh[If[u == 1, test = False;, u += 1/100], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> .1], Catch@Throw[u]]
] ]
```

"test" is the variable responsibile for stopping and realasing time.
This is not very sophisticated but it works. I'd love to see more simple way.

Other way is to use `RunScheduledTask[n++,{1,Infinity}]` and in the moment You want, `RemoveScheduledTask@ScheduledTasks[]`, but I had problems with creating funtion with `Module` for this.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but can you explain how this solves my problem? I don't see how I could use a button to reset that progress bar.

Comment: You can put that `Button[]` in this DynamicModule so it will be able to set u=0 and test="False".
I hope it is helpful, but ask if You have any doubts.

Comment: Hi Kuba, thanks so much for your answer.  I eventually got it working, and it does what I need.  I also wish there was a simpler way; there *must* be a way to do this using Clock[], but for now, this is definitely great.