# Start animation after choosing of initial values without Animate

Tags: animation, conditional

I want to simply set some parameters with sliders and click a button to start animation.

I know that I can manage this with Animate and Manipulate, but my animation is written like in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17584/10594), because I need to perform some calculations for stop condition.

So the point is that I want to start loop after setting parameters and clicking button. Is it achievable?

//edit

Ok, lets say that in the animation from linked post is some variable m

```
Clear[p];
Dynamic[p]
Do[p = Plot[m Cos[a x], {x, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {x, 
  Style[Column[{"doing my own animation !", Cos[a x]}, 
    Alignment -> Center], 14]}}, GridLines -> Automatic];
If[a > 0.2, Break[]]; (*condition to stop*)
Pause[.2],
{a, 0.1, 1, .01}
]
```

I'd like to start this animation with button, and before that set **m** with slider.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! With the setup from the link, try `Dynamic[p]` on one line and `Button["start", Do[...]]` on another or in another cell.  Please note that in its present form, this question does not include enough details for people to give specific, accurate answers.  Please include code that illustrates the problem -- feel free to copy the code from the linked post if it accurately illustrates your problem.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that after clicking button I get animation but last frame(already done).

Comment: Note that the goal, "to start loop after setting parameters and clicking button", can be achieved with `Animate` and `Manipulate`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a slider for setting `m`, try this:

```
Row[{Slider[Dynamic @ m, {0.1, 1, .01}], "  ", Dynamic @ m}]
```

[image: slider.png]

```
topLbl = 
  Style[Column[{"Doing my own animation!", Dynamic @ m Cos[a x]}, Alignment -> Center], 14];

Button[
  "Start",
  Do[
    p = Plot[m Cos[a x], {x, 0, 100},
      Frame -> True,
      FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {x, topLbl}},
      GridLines -> Automatic];
    If[a > 0.2, Break[]];
    Pause[.2],
    {a, 0.1, 1, .01}],
  Method -> "Queued"]
```

[image: button.png]

```
Dynamic[p]
```

[image: plot.png]