# Manipulate: Play the animation only once and stop

Tags: manipulate

I do small animations with `Manipulate`, but sometimes I don't like that it runs over and over again from start. I would like to have the possibility to stop the animation after one run at the end of the parameter interval. 
Is there a way to get it this way?

Comment: Use `Animate` with `AnimationRepetitions -> 1`.

Comment: I believe this can be closed as a duplicate of: [(17571)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17571/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the question is valid. The OP asked about Manipulate not Animate.

Comment: @Algohi Fair enough.  However if a good solution is to use `Animate` one must ask why that option is rejected?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,I agree that the good solution is to use Animate. It will be good if someone finds a solution for Manipulate too.

Comment: The difference between [(17571)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17571/121) and this question is how to get the behavior of `Animate` in a `Manipulate` that might have other controls in it.  `Manipulate` does not take the `AnimationRepetitions` options, so the solutions to 17571 do not solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

The default `Manipulator`, `` FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "Manipulator04"] ``,  does not allow the option `AnimationRepetitions` to be passed to the `Animator` used by the `Manipulator`.  However, there is another `` FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "Manipulator05"] ``, that does allows further options to be passed.  See

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,
  "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "MiscExpressions.tr"}]
```

Also see my answer here:
[Logarithmic slider](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28457/logarithmic-slider/28501#28501)

However, the method used in my answer to that question does not work if I use `` FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "Manipulator05"] ``.  Instead we can adapt the code for it to this situation.  (This cumbersome workaround may convince one that `Animator` is a better choice for a simple application as described by the OP. In a more complicated `Manipulate`, this solution may still have some value.)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[myvariable x, {x, 0, 100}],
 {myvariable, 0.1, 1, 
   myManipulator[##, AnimationRunning -> True, AnimationRepetitions -> 1] &}]
```

The code for `myManipulator` and the `"Manipulator05"` workaround `man05` are given below.

Let me first point out the following way to combine the `Animate` behavior with a more general `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[myvariable x, {x, 0, 100}], {myvariable, 0.1, 1, Animator, 
  AnimationRunning -> True, AnimationRepetitions -> 1}]
```

This is basically all `Animate` does anyway.

**Code dump**

```
ClearAll[myManipulator];
Options[myManipulator] = 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   Join[Options[Manipulator], Options[Slider], Options[Animator], 
    Options[InputField]], First];
With[{smallerRule = {Large -> Medium, Medium -> Small, 
    Small -> Tiny}}, 
 myManipulator[Dynamic[x_], range_: {0, 1}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   With[{imagesize = OptionValue[ImageSize] /. Automatic -> Medium, 
    inputfieldsize = 
     OptionValue[ImageSize] /. Automatic -> Medium /. smallerRule, 
    enabled = OptionValue[Enabled], 
    continuousaction = OptionValue[ContinuousAction], 
    appearance = 
     First[Cases[OptionValue[Appearance], 
        Tiny | Small | Medium | Large] /. {} -> {Automatic}], 
    labeled = ! FreeQ[OptionValue[Appearance], "Labeled"] || ! 
       FreeQ[OptionValue[AppearanceElements], "InlineInputField"], 
    opener = 
     OptionValue[AppearanceElements] /. {Automatic -> True, 
       All -> True, None -> False, 
       l_List :> (Cases[l, Except["InlineInputField"]] =!= {})}, 
    inputfield = 
     MatchQ[OptionValue[AppearanceElements], Automatic | All] || ! 
       FreeQ[OptionValue[AppearanceElements], "InputField"], 
    appearanceelements = 
     OptionValue[AppearanceElements] /. {Automatic -> All, None -> {},
        l_List :> 
        Cases[l, Except["InlineInputField" | "InputField"]]}, 
    autoaction = OptionValue[AutoAction], 
    exclusions = OptionValue[Exclusions]}, 
   ReleaseHold@
    MakeExpression[
     PaneBox[DynamicModuleBox[{Typeset`open$$ = ! 
          FreeQ[OptionValue[Appearance], "Open"], 
        Typeset`paused$$ = OptionValue[PausedTime], 
        Typeset`rate$$ = OptionValue[AnimationRate], 
        Typeset`dir$$ = OptionValue[AnimationDirection]}, 
       StyleBox[DynamicBox[man05[
          Dynamic[x],
          Dynamic[x],
          range,
          imagesize,
          inputfieldsize,
          enabled,
          continuousaction,
          appearance,
          labeled,
          opener,
          inputfield,
          appearanceelements,
          autoaction,
          exclusions,
          Dynamic[Typeset`open$$],
          Dynamic[Typeset`paused$$],
          Dynamic[Typeset`rate$$],
          Dynamic[Typeset`dir$$],
          FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Slider]],
          FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Animator]],
          FilterRules[{opts}, Options[InputField]],
          FilterRules[{opts}, Options[InputField]],(* 
          inline InputField *)
          Expression,(* 
          InputField type *)
          OptionValue[BaseStyle],
          OptionValue[LabelStyle]
          ]
         ],
        DynamicUpdating -> True], DynamicModuleValues :> {}], 
      BaselinePosition -> (OptionValue[BaselinePosition] /. 
         Automatic -> Baseline), 
      ImageMargins -> OptionValue[ImageMargins]], StandardForm]]]

man05 = StyleBox[
            PaneSelectorBox[{
                False -> GridBox[{
                        Join[
                            {SliderBox[#2, #3, Join[#19, {
                                        ImageSize -> #4,
                                        Enabled -> #6,
                                        ContinuousAction -> #7,
                                        Appearance -> #8,
                                        AutoAction -> #13,
                                        Exclusions -> #14}]]},
                            If[#10,
                                {ItemBox[TooltipBox[TogglerBox[#15, {

                True -> DynamicBox[
                  FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", 
                   "SquareMinusIcon"]],

                False -> DynamicBox[
                  FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", 
                   "SquarePlusIcon"]]},
                                    Appearance -> None,
                                    ImageSize -> Automatic
                                    ], 
              FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEStrings", 
               "ManipulatorTooltipShowControls"]], 
             Alignment -> {Left}]}, {}],
                            If[#9,
                                {InputFieldBox[#1, #23, Join[#22, {
                                        FieldSize -> {{4, 10}, {1, 2}},
                                        Enabled -> #6,
                                        Appearance -> {"Frameless", #8},

               BaseStyle -> Join[{"Manipulator"}, #25]}]]}, {}]
                            ]},
                        ColumnSpacings -> 0.6,
                        BaselinePosition -> {{1, 1}, Axis}],
                True -> GridBox[{
                        Join[
                            {SliderBox[#2, #3, Join[#19, {
                                        ImageSize -> #4,
                                        Enabled -> #6,
                                        ContinuousAction -> #7,
                                        Appearance -> #8,
                                        AutoAction -> #13,
                                        Exclusions -> #14}]]},
                            If[#10,
                                {ItemBox[TooltipBox[TogglerBox[#15, {

                True -> DynamicBox[
                  FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", 
                   "SquareMinusIcon"]],

                False -> DynamicBox[
                  FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", 
                   "SquarePlusIcon"]]},
                                    Appearance -> None,
                                    ImageSize -> Automatic
                                    ], 
              FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEStrings", 
               "ManipulatorTooltipHideControls"]], 
             Alignment -> {Left}]}, {}],
                            If[#9,
                                {InputFieldBox[#1, #23, Join[#22, {
                                        FieldSize -> {{4, 10}, {1, 2}},
                                        Enabled -> #6,
                                        Appearance -> {"Frameless", #8},

               BaseStyle -> Join[{"Manipulator"}, #25]}]]}, {}]
                            ],
                        Join[
                            {GridBox[{{
                                    StyleBox[
                                        InputFieldBox[#1, #23, Join[#21, {
                                                ImageSize -> {60, #5},
                                                ImageMargins -> {{10, 0}, {0, 0}},
                                                Enabled -> #6,
                                                Appearance -> #8,

                  BaseStyle -> 
                   Join[{"Manipulator"}, #24, {FontSize :> 
                    CurrentValue[{"ControlsFontSize", #5}]}]}]],
                                        ShowContents -> #11],
                                    AnimatorBox[#2, #3, Join[#20, {
                                            AnimationRate -> #17,
                                            ImageSize -> #4,
                                            Enabled -> #6,
                                            PausedTime -> #16,
                                            AnimationDirection -> #18,
                                            Appearance -> #8,
                                            AppearanceElements -> Dynamic[

                   If[#12 === All, {"StepLeftButton", 
                    "StepRightButton", "PlayPauseButton", 
                    "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}, #12]],
                                            Exclusions -> #14}]]
                                    }},
                                    ColumnSpacings -> {1.1},
                                    RowAlignments -> Center,
                                    RowMinHeight -> 0]},
                            If[#9, {"\[SpanFromLeft]"}, {}],
                            If[#10, {"\[SpanFromLeft]"}, {}]
                        ]},
                        ColumnAlignments -> Left,
                        ColumnSpacings -> 0.6,
                        RowSpacings -> {0.4, 0},
                        RowMinHeight -> 0.1,
                        BaselinePosition -> {{1, 1}, Axis}]},
                #15, 
                ImageSize -> Automatic, BaselinePosition -> Baseline],
            Deployed -> True,
            TooltipBoxOptions -> {ActionDelay -> Automatic}] &;
```

Comment: I still wonder why ``FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "Manipulator05"]`` in place of `man05` does not work.  Perhaps it late and I'm too tired to recognize a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to make a Play button to make it play once. Does it have to use the Mathematica build in play button? Here is an example: (if this is not what you meant, please provide more information)

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 If[f < maxFrequency,
  tick = Not[tick];
  f += 0.01];
 Plot[Sin[2 Pi f t], {t, -10, 10}],
 {{maxFrequency, 1, "max frequencey? (Hz)"}, .1, 2, .01},
 Button["play once", f = 0; tick = Not[tick]],
 {{tick, False}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to show you my Mathematica command, but I dont know how to embedded into this comment.

Comment: As a plain copy paste, my code goes like this:

Manipulate[
 Plot[1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (\[Sigma] + t)) 
   E^(-x^2/(\[Sigma] + t)^2), {x, -50, 50}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {0, 0.5}}], {\[Sigma], 1, 2}, {t, 0, 50}]

Comment: Maybe you can copy paste it to Mathematica notepad, to have it neat. My point is that when I run the variable t in Manipulate window, I would like it to run only once, not repeat.

I wish a nice evening

Answer (score 4):

You can set `AnimationRepetitions -> 1` as a suboption in [`DefaultOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultOptions.html):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[u x, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}], 
 {u, 0.1, 1, DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> {AnimationRepetitions -> 1}}}]
```

[image]

Add `AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward` as an option either in control

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[u x, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}], 
 {u, 0.1, 1, 
  AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward, 
  DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> {AnimationRepetitions -> 1}}}]
```

or inside `DefaultOptions`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[u x, {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}], 
 {u, 0.1, 1, 
  DefaultOptions -> 
     {Animator -> {AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
         AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward}}}]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Very helpful...  (Oh... for what it is worth, I thanked you in my newly published book, ***Pixels & paintings***.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thank you thank you thank you. Beautiful book! (Very timely too --  as a gift for my daughter's upcoming birthday:)