# Eliminating the backward play in a SWF export of Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, export

I find that the `Export` of `Manipuate` contains backforward play, see a simplified example:

```
Export["try.swf", 
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[2 x + φ], {x, 0, 10}], {φ, 0, 2 π}]]
```

You can see the problem in the SWF file.

Is there any simple way to get a animation with only forward play?

Note that the problem in the the `Export` command. Indeed, `Manipulate` does the job (no need to specify `AnimationDirection -> Forward`).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: My answer here can be adapted, too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71761/ (Just replace the `DeleteDuplicate[..]` in `autolist` for the `Manipulator` with `{min, max}`.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way (I think) is to set bookmarks.  Then `Export` will interpolate between them.

```
Export["try.swf",
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[2*x + φ], {x, 0, 10}],
  {{φ, 5.2308285471612335}, 0, 2*Pi},
   Bookmarks -> 
   {"start" :> {φ = 0.}, 
    "stop" :> {φ = 2. Pi}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Tanks a lot @Michael E2! That's amazing ;-)

Comment: I'm sure many people would like this answer, but they can't necessarily retrieve it here