# Animate to gif without looping forwards and then backwards with all the frames

Tags: graphics, export, animation

I want to create a gif where a graph is "losing" edges. I have the following code that creates a list of graphs.

```
eg = {1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 13, 1 <-> 15, 1 <-> 21, 1 <-> 22, 
   1 <-> 30, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 7, 2 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9, 2 <-> 15, 2 <-> 25, 
   3 <-> 15, 3 <-> 16, 3 <-> 26, 3 <-> 28, 3 <-> 30, 4 <-> 12, 
   4 <-> 20, 4 <-> 22, 4 <-> 28, 5 <-> 8, 5 <-> 9, 5 <-> 11, 5 <-> 17,
    5 <-> 24, 5 <-> 25, 6 <-> 9, 6 <-> 15, 6 <-> 19, 6 <-> 21, 
   6 <-> 22, 7 <-> 22, 7 <-> 23, 7 <-> 27, 8 <-> 9, 8 <-> 10, 
   8 <-> 15, 8 <-> 22, 8 <-> 28, 9 <-> 11, 9 <-> 18, 10 <-> 13, 
   10 <-> 17, 10 <-> 25, 10 <-> 26, 10 <-> 29, 10 <-> 30, 11 <-> 17, 
   11 <-> 26, 11 <-> 30, 12 <-> 21, 12 <-> 24, 12 <-> 27, 13 <-> 14, 
   14 <-> 22, 15 <-> 21, 15 <-> 26, 15 <-> 30, 16 <-> 22, 17 <-> 22, 
   17 <-> 27, 17 <-> 28, 18 <-> 19, 18 <-> 20, 18 <-> 23, 19 <-> 24, 
   19 <-> 25, 19 <-> 27, 19 <-> 28, 20 <-> 24, 20 <-> 29, 21 <-> 26, 
   22 <-> 28, 24 <-> 25, 24 <-> 28, 25 <-> 29, 25 <-> 30, 27 <-> 29};

re = {};
be = eg;
ES = Join[Table[i -> {Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.001]}, {i, re}], 
   Table[i -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, {i, be}]];
glist = {Graph[eg, EdgeStyle -> ES, VertexSize -> 0.7]};

Do[
 re = Join[re, RandomChoice[be, 1]];
 be = Complement[eg, re];
 ES = Join[Table[i -> {Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.001]}, {i, re}], 
   Table[i -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, {i, be}]];

 AppendTo[glist, Graph[eg, EdgeStyle -> ES, VertexSize -> 0.7]],
 {i, Length[eg]}]
```

After that I use `Animate` to animate this.

```
an = Animate[glist[[i]], {i, 1, Length[glist], 1}, DefaultDuration -> 20, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationDirection -> Forward]
```

After that I `Export` it to gif.

```
Export["edgeloss.gif", an, "ControlAppearance" -> None]
```

The problem I have with this is that the gif loops forwards and then backwards and also loses some of the frames. You can see it here: https://pasteboard.co/H9hZK6D.gif

I tried to export the list of graphs but the graph "vibrates" as frames change which is very annoying. You can see it here: https://pasteboard.co/H9hYhec.gif

Is there a way to have all the frames and having the gif only looping forward? Alternatively, can the list be animated without vibration?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you? Note that I export `glist` converted to graphics via `Show`, not the output of `Animate`. I set `PlotRange` manually in order to avoid jiggling.

```
s = Max[PropertyValue[glist[[1]], VertexSize]];
g = Show[glist[[1]]];
plora = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g];
plora[[All, 1]] -= 0.25 s;
plora[[All, 2]] += 0.25 s;
Export["edgeloss.gif",
 Map[Rasterize[Show[#, PlotRange -> plora]] &, glist],
 "DisplayDurations" -> .1,
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1
 ]
```

Comment: As  I said, this has all the frames and loops only forwards, but the graph vibrates for me. Doesn't it do that for you?

Comment: Nope, it does not vibrate for me... Maybe you can post your GIF in your question. I am not very sure what exactly vibrates in the plots...

Comment: I cannot put the gif in my answer, so I have uploaded and given the link.

Comment: Hm. I see. So the relative positions of the vertices remain fixed. Must have some thing to do with the way `PlotRange` gets computed.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I have no clue how to control that. I guess one way could be to use `GraphPlot` but I cannot control the style there. It just baffles me that I cannot control how `animate` gets exported. It should be the default way to create animations.

Comment: Ah, wait, I just saw your edit. I will try that.

Comment: It does vibrate less now (https://pasteboard.co/H9ibj1Jx.gif) You said that you didn't have this problem in the first place, right? Which mathematica do you have? I have 11.1.1.0. By the way, I guess instead of `g` you meant to write `glist[[1]]`, right?

Comment: Oh, I forgot: `g = Show[glist[[1]]]` (added it now together with `Rasterize`; have a try). I use version 11.0.1 for macos.

Comment: OK, I cannot make any sense of it. What you propose doesn't work and actually cannot work. I created a table with length 81 with just the `Show` first graph and exported it to gif and it wiggles. (https://pasteboard.co/H9imnE3.gif) I will submit a bug report, this makes no sense. I have the linux version by the way.

Comment: Do that. (Maybe it is only about the GIF exporter. You could also try to export the frames to PNG and use, e.g.  ffmpeg, to create the animated GIF file.)

Comment: It doesn't work. I exported the same graph 30 times and the movie wiggles! I quit. My gif will wiggle, I don't care anymore. I submitted a bug report by the way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @tst You can simply add `Bookmarks`, see the thread
[Eliminating the backward play in a SWF export of Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81190/eliminating-the-backward-play-in-a-swf-export-of-manipulate)